# How to make multiple files in an array with HTML5 form data object?

Tags: jquery, html, form-data, jquery-1.9

I want to get a multiple files in an array with HTML5 form data object,

```
// HTML5 form data object.
var fd = new FormData();
jQuery.each(fileList, function (i, file) {
    fd.append('file[' + i + ']', file);
});
```

result,

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1402236_566802636708984_1354256864_o.jpg
                    [1] => 287481_456592524374335_1348353782_o.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php5A1E.tmp
                    [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\php5A21.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 217360
                    [1] => 144071
                )

        )

)
```

but I am after this result,

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 1402236_566802636708984_1354256864_o.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php35C1.tmp
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 217360
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 964570_566803006708947_840223346_o.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php35C4.tmp
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 518594
                )
        )

)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started:

```
var newArr=[],
    keys= $.map(files.file,function( value, key){
        return key
    }),
        numFiles= files.file[keys[0]].length;

    for( i=0; i< numFiles; i++){
        var f={};
        $.each(keys, function( keyIdx, key){
           f[key]= files.file[key][i]; 
        });
        newArr.push(f);
    }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ugfpW/)**</kbd>

Comment: np... these remapping scenarios are great practice. I don't know the formdata api very well...probably a simple way to get total files from a native method also